# How to prevent listview from refreshing automatically?

Tags: android, image, class, android-studio, listview

I'm creating a music player application for android. In my custom listview I have title,artist and album art. I'm using universal image loader to load album art in the imageview. The problem is listview is lagging while scrolling. In the logs I checked that listviewadapter is running again and again whenever I scroll up or down. Is there a way to prevent listviewadapter from updating again and again. Here is my custom listviewadapter.

```
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.memory.impl.WeakMemoryCache;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;

public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WorldPopulation> {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                           List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist) {
        super(context, resourceId, worldpopulationlist);
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        this.context = context;
        this.worldpopulationlist = worldpopulationlist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView artist;
        ImageView albumArt;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        setupImageLoader();
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_artist_album_art, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_title);
            holder.artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songs_artist);
            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            holder.albumArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        holder.title.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).gettitle());
        holder.artist.setText(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getartist());
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        //noinspection deprecation
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.album_art)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.album_art)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.album_art).build();

//        Bitmap artwork = null;
//        try {
//            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
//            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Long.valueOf(worldpopulationlist.get(position).getalbumArt()));
//            ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
//            InputStream in = res.openInputStream(uri);
//            artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
//
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
//            artwork = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.album_art);
//        }
//        holder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(artwork);
        imageLoader.displayImage("content://media/external/audio/albumart/" + worldpopulationlist.get(position).getalbumArt(),holder.albumArt,options);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(WorldPopulation object) {
        worldpopulationlist.remove(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<WorldPopulation> getWorldPopulation() {
        return worldpopulationlist;
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int position) {
        selectView(position, !mSelectedItemsIds.get(position));
    }

    public void removeSelection() {
        mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void selectView(int position, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            mSelectedItemsIds.put(position, value);
        else
            mSelectedItemsIds.delete(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedCount() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds.size();
    }

    public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
        return mSelectedItemsIds;
    }

    private void setupImageLoader(){
        // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        //noinspection deprecation
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

        //noinspection deprecation
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache()).discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you set this to false? *.resetViewBeforeLoading(true)*

Comment: I didn't understand what you saying??